# Magento 2 : Using default store, view, themes

Tags: magento2, theme, store-view, magento2.2.3

I've been working with magento 2.2 for about 2 months.  Another individual set up our website to this point.  He used the "main website" in Stores|Settings|Stores.
He used the default Store view, and he used the default Luma theme.
And... he made all of his edits to the website in the default luma theme.

As I've been reading I've realized that this is not good policy, and at least a new theme should have been created.

So here are my questions:

1. is it ok to use the default main website store?
2. is it ok to use the default store view?
3. is there a way for me to copy the edited Luma theme into a new theme?
4. if I'm missing the point, what is the best way to resolve this issue?

Thanks for everyone's input.

Answer (score 0):

Here are answer of your question.

1. Yes, you can use default main website store. (You need to create another website if you need multi website)
2. Yes, you can use default store view. (You can also create another store view if you want in future)
3. Better way, you create new theme and set it parent to Luma theme.